# Sharepoint2013 Site - CSOM - Update Navigation Settings

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

We need to update Global and Current Navigation Settings for the site.
Below is our code

```
var publishingWeb  = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(this.CC, subWeb);

                    // WebNavigationSettings
                    var webNavigationSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(this.CC, subWeb);
                    webNavigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;
                    webNavigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.PortalProvider;

                    // CSOM don't have: publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites.
                    subWeb.AllProperties["__GlobalIncludeSubSites"] = "True"; //TODO: Verify why it is not working. 
                    subWeb.AllProperties["__GlobalIncludePages"] = "True"; //TODO: Verify why it is not working.

                    subWeb.Update();
                    webNavigationSettings.Update(tSession);

                    CC.Load(subWeb, WEB_INCLUDES);

                    // Apply the load
                    CC.ExecuteQuery();
```

As we are using CSOM, we did not have

> publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites

.
So we tried to set using AllProperties to set GlobalIncludeSubSites and GlobalIncludePages.

---

But those properties are not getting set.
Is there any way to fix this problem.
I went throught article http://discoveringsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/programmatically-set-navigation-settings-in-sharepoint-2013/
But it uses namespace : Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation

---

But our's namespace is : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation
As we are doing from client server object model.
Is there any way to solve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In SharePoint 2013 was introduced a new [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing(v=office.15).aspx) and [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.navigation(v=office.15).aspx) namespaces in CSOM API. But unfortunately it is *not supported* to modify navigation settings using [WebNavigationSettings class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.publishing.navigation.webnavigationsettings(v=office.15).aspx) since properties are exposes as a *read-only*.

You could utilize the following approach for that purpose. [ClientPortalNavigation.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7090347) represents a CSOM counterpart for SSOM [PortalNavigation Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.portalnavigation(v=office.14).aspx).

The following example demonstrates how to utilize that class and update Navigation settings:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{

    var navigation = new ClientPortalNavigation(ctx.Web);
    navigation.CurrentIncludePages = true;
    navigation.GlobalIncludePages = false;
    navigation.SaveChanges();   
}
```

> [ClientPortalNavigation.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7090347) is compatible with SharePoint 2010/2013
>   CSOM APIs.

### References

- [Access and Manipulate Navigation Settings via SharePoint Client Object Model](http://blog.vgrem.com/2013/10/22/access-and-manipulate-navigation-settings-via-sharepoint-client-object-model/)
- [ClientPortalNavigation.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7090347)